# NextJs / React: Organizing Array

Tags: reactjs, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6, next.js

I'm having issues understanding how to best manipulate an array to get the data I want. From the research I've done, there's multiple ways, but I'm unclear on which is most optimized.

I want to display a simple list, with the items broken down by country, then state, then organized alphabetically by city. The array is formatted as follows:

```
[
 {
  id: 1,
  name: "Place 1",
  state: "Florida",
  city: "Boca Raton",
  country: "US",
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  name: "Place 2",
  state: "Florida",
  city: "Daytona Beach",
  country: "US",
 },
 {
  id: 3,
  name: "Place 3",
  state: "Kansas",
  city: "Lenexa",
  country: "US",
 },
{
  id: 4,
  name: "Place 4",
  state: "Harju",
  city: "Tallinn",
  country: "EE",
 },
]
```

An example of the desired outcome is:

## US

### Florida

- Place 1
- Place 2

### Kansas

- Place 3

## EE

### Harju

- Place 4

I see a lot of people saying to utilize ES6 for this, but I'm not sure the best way to approach it. Manipulate the original array response? Is there some way I can loop through them?

Comment: The best way would be to map through this array with simple `.map()` function :)

Comment: I've manipulated the array using reduce to sort them by "State". I then did `{Object.keys(array).map((key) =>` and looped it once to sort by state. Is there a way to do this without manipulating the original array using .map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that only requires a single loop.

```
const data = [];
let result = {};
data.forEach(({ name, state, country }) => {
  if (!result[country]) {
    result[country] = {};
  }
  if (!result[country][state]) {
    result[country][state] = [name];
  }
  else {
    result[country] = {
      ...result[country],
      [state]: [
        ...result[country][state],
        name
      ]
    };
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

Output

```
{
  US: { Florida: [ 'Place 1', 'Place 2' ], Kansas: [ 'Place 3' ] },
  EE: { Harju: [ 'Place 4' ] }
}
```

<strike>I'm sure the if-else part can be removed by using spread operator and operator chaining, but I wasn't able to figure that out.</strike>

If your environment supports operator chaining, here's a smaller solution

```
const data = [];
let result = {};
data.forEach(({ name, state, country }) => {
  result[country] = {
    ...result[country],
    [state]: [
      ...(result?.[country]?.[state] || []),
      name
    ]
  };
});

console.log(result);
```